# Disable a div tags that contain the same attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two div tags with a different id but has the same attribute like the following below:
The first div tag:

```
<div id="espresso-option" class="option">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="type">
      <p>Type<p>
          <input type="radio" id="houseEspresso" name="type" checked="checked" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="houseEspresso">House Espresso</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="guestEspresso" name="type" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="guestEspresso">Guest Espresso</label><br>
    </div>
    <div class="size">
      <p>Size<p>
          <input type="radio" id="single" name="size" value="25000" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="single">Single Espresso</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="double" name="size" value="50000" checked="checked" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="double">Double Espresso</label><br>
    </div>
    <div class="extra">
      <p>Extras<p>
          <input type="radio" id="none" name="extra" value="0" checked="checked" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="milk">None</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="hotmilk" name="extra" value="10000" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="hotmilk">Hot milk</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="coldmilk" name="extra" value="10000" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="coldmilk">Cold milk</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chocolate" name="extra" value="10000" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="chocolate">Chocolate Dusting</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="marshmallow" name="extra" value="10000" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="marshmallow">Marshmallows</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="cream" name="extra" value="10000" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="cream">Whipped Cream</label><br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="add-to-cart">
    <strong class="product-price-title">Price: </strong>
    <span class="product-price">0</span>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-cart">Add product</button>

</div>
```

The second div tag:

```
<div id="cappuccino-option" class="option">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="type">
      <p>Type<p>
          <input type="radio" id="houseEspresso" name="type" checked="checked" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="houseEspresso">House Espresso</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="guestEspresso" name="type" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="guestEspresso">Guest Espresso</label><br>
    </div>
    <div class="size">
      <p>Size<p>
          <input type="radio" id="small" name="size" value="30000" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="small">Small</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="medium" name="size" value="45000" checked="checked" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="medium">Medium</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="large" name="size" value="67500" checked="checked" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="large">Large</label><br>
    </div>
    <div class="extra">
      <p>Extras<p>
          <input type="radio" id="none" name="extra" value="0" checked="checked" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="milk">None</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="hotmilk" name="extra" value="10000" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="hotmilk">Hot milk</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="coldmilk" name="extra" value="10000" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="coldmilk">Cold milk</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chocolate" name="extra" value="10000" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="chocolate">Chocolate Dusting</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="marshmallow" name="extra" value="10000" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="marshmallow">Marshmallows</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="cream" name="extra" value="10000" onclick="addProduct(this)">
          <label for="cream">Whipped Cream</label><br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="add-to-cart">
    <strong class="product-price-title">Price: </strong>
    <span class="product-price">0</span>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-cart">Add product</button>

</div>
```

What I am trying to do here is that I want to use javascript to calculate the price of different product (for example: espresso and cappuccino) and add to cart. When I click choose the first option (the first div tag), I hope it work without any relative to the second option (the second div tag).
Here is my javascript for this function:

```
function addProduct(){
var size = document.getElementsByName("size");
var extra = document.getElementsByName("extra");
var priceOfProduct = 0;
var priceOfSize = 0;
var priceOfExtra = 0;

for (var i=0; i<size.length; i++){
    if(size[i].checked){
        priceOfSize = size[i].value
    }
}

for (var i=0; i<extra.length; i++){
    if(extra[i].checked){
        priceOfExtra += parseFloat(extra[i].value)
    }
}

priceOfProduct =+(priceOfSize) + +(priceOfExtra.toFixed(2))
document.getElementsByClassName("product-price")[0].innerText = priceOfProduct}
```

This function worked well whether there is only one type of product. However, when I add one or more product, it seems not to work correctly since it has the same name of button when I use "getElementsByName".
Can anyone give me an idea for this issue? I am trying to solve it just by using pure HTML, css and javascript. Thank you so much!

Comment: use `x.querySelector('[name="product-price"]')` - where `x` is the `div` you're working with

Comment: I am not sure about your business logic but in for loop if you are adding then + operatior is required to sum up which is missing in size for lopp.  priceOfSize = size[i].value should be priceOfSize += size[i].value

Comment: @JaromandaX But if I have more than 5 or 10 product, how my javascript function work with this?

Comment: @AmitVerma Actually with "size", I chose to use the radio button so then it only needs one price at all. However, thank you for your recommendation.

Comment: by calling the function correctly

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p id="price-size">Size</p>
```

```js
let size = document.getElementById("espresso-option").querySelectorAll("p#price-size").value;
```

Comment: Could you please explain more? If I have more than 5 or 10 product, how my javascript function work with this?